# compiz and unity crash after AMD drivers installed

Tags: unity, ati, compiz

I'm a new linux user. I recently installed AMD drivers from `software center`. When I restarted my machine, the normal login screen with the top menu bar appeared but after login I  only have my wallpaper with no `Launcher` and the top menu bar.

I have HP dv6-6150ew laptop with intel/AMD hybrid CPU (intel HD3000/Radeon 6770HD) and I must install drivers because without them my laptop is overheating and it shuts down.

Any advice what i can do?

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

Type in this command `gnome-control-center`.

And you would be able to access additional drives to get back to the normal x.org driver.

Note:
if your laptop is really overheating there will be an emergency shutdown by the computer itself so don't worry :) ?

Comment: When i revert to open source drivers im not able to login into my account. I have normal login screen and im able to login as guest but when i try to login as normal user screen gos blac for a sec and return me to login screen

Comment: Strange I would recommend to repair your ubuntu installation using the CD / USB. Or just re-install the whole thing. That you go back to login is certainly (correct me if I am wrong) no driver issue.

Comment: I have login problem after installing drivers. Install was fresh and I do nothing else. I will try reinstall ubuntu.